# node.js returns GMT time and not local time for "new Date()". Is that a bug?

Tags: javascript, datetime, node.js, date

If not a bug, how to tell node my timezone?
If bug, is this reported already?

Comment: Since you know your own timezone in relation to GMT, can't you just adjust with the proper offset? Seems like it's appropriate with GMT to be flexible about different server locations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug, just a choice of how Node decides to represent a `Date` object in its REPL.  Also, as of node `v0.7.x`, this output has been changed to display local time, matching the browser behavior:

```
☮ ~ (master) ⚡ node
> process.version
'v0.7.7'
> new Date
Sat Mar 31 2012 15:12:13 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

Comment: Displaying date in a console is not standardized yet in ECMAScript. So this doesn't matter. Credits to @TooTallNate

Comment: behavior is still the same in node 6.9.4. shouldn't it return based on machine settings by default (as the browser does)?

Comment: As of `v10.15 LTS`, the behavior is still as it is (getting UTC instead of local time)! Was this bug "unfixed" sometime in between?

Answer (score 7):

If it is a bug, it does not exist in my version of Node. It is true that the Node.js REPL prefers to announce in GMT in my version:

```
> new Date()
Sat, 31 Mar 2012 21:51:47 GMT
```

But it is in fact timezone-aware, that is just not what the REPL shows when stringifying it:

```
> new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
-120
> "" + new Date()
'Sat Mar 31 2012 23:51:56 GMT+0200 (CEST)'
```

(I am running Node.js v0.6.1 on Ubuntu.)

Comment: This does look like a bug to me.